# как сделать чтобы данные выводились не в текстовое поле а в абзац?

Tags: javascript, html

у меня есть код

```
function getArray() {
  const form = document.querySelector('form');
  const arr1 = form.arr1.value.split(',');
  const arr2 = form.arr2.value.split(',');
  
  const union = [...new Set(arr1.concat(arr2))];
  form.result.value = union;
}
<form name="test">
  Серия значений 1:<br>
  <input name="arr1"><br>
  Серия значений 2:<br>
  <input name="arr2"><br>
  Результат:<br>
  <input name="result"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Получить результат" onclick="getArray()"> 
</form>
```

как сделать чтобы данные выводились не в текстовое поле а в абзац?

Comment: Полный азбац! Как сделать так, чтобы понять о чем ты спрашиваешь?

Answer (score 4):

```js
function getArray() {
  const form = document.querySelector('form');
  const arr1 = form.arr1.value.split(/\s*,\s*/);
  const arr2 = form.arr2.value.split(/\s*,\s*/);

  const union = [...new Set(arr1.concat(arr2))];

  const box = document.getElementById('result');
  box.innerHTML = union.join(', ');
}
```

```html
<form name="test">
  Серия значений 1:<br>
  <input name="arr1"><br> Серия значений 2:<br>
  <input name="arr2"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Получить результат" onclick="getArray()">
</form>
<p>Результат:<br><span id="result"></span></p>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]